# Combining while in foreach in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I have been working for a while to combine a "foreach loop" and a "while loop". I would like my foreach to run 30 times. This is indicated by **$counter**. Now the problem is that my "while" again starts the "foreach" every time. But it hears 30 times turning the "while" each time again.

If I get the while part away and use static code, it will work completely. But I need to link my DB for the information. Perhaps an option is to make a "foreach" a "for" or a whole different option. But I have no idea how to set him up.

$counter = days in a month

$index = foreach time for running. Max $counter

$NUM = unique number of 1 people

**The $ index together with $ cut_startday together indicate when a box is to be red or green.**

Here's the code for the none working foreach:

```
 foreach(range(1,$counter) as $index) {/*open foreach*/
                       $get_data = "
                            SELECT * 
                            FROM core";



    $result1 = $conn->query($get_data) or die($conn ->error);


    //Start query 1
    if($result1) {
                    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {


            // Get NUM, START DATE and END DATE
            $NUM = ($row['c_m_num']);
            $startdate = ($row['e_date_s']);
            $enddate = ($row['e_date_e']);

            // Cut strings for date
            $sort_year = substr($startdate, 6, 4); // START YEAR -> 2017
            $sort_month = substr($startdate, 0, 2); // START MONTH -> 09
            $cut_startday = substr($startdate, 3, 2); // START DAY -> 17
            $cut_endday = substr($enddate, 3, 2); // END DAY -> 19



                         if($load_m_NUM == "$NUM" and $index >= $cut_startday && $index <= $cut_endday ){
                            echo"<td style='background-color:red;'>x</td>";
                            }


                            else{
                    echo"<td style='background-color:green;'></td>";
                    }


        }

        }           



/*end foreach*/ }
```

What the idea is of the code. I want a calendar with a top row de days of a month and on the left side al the people. If the core find a match between days and 1 men, color the td red if not color green.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's starting the foreach each time? Try echoing out the `$index` at the top of the foreach loop to verify.

Comment: Though, what's the purpose of it? You're going to echo out everything from your `core` table 30 times.

Comment: The pupose of the code is now in my question. Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the foreach statement to `for ($index = 0; $index < 30; $index++)`. To improve your code I suggest putting the for loop inside the while loop instead. That way you only query the database once instead of 30 times.

Comment: For that matter, the OP could bypass the for loop, and just add `LIMIT 30` to their query.

Comment: May be, but I don't think so. He's doing some colored table cells based on `$index`. Don't know what he's up to...

Comment: Thx! What the idea is of the code. I want a calendar with a top row de days of a month and on the left side al the people. If the core find a match between days and 1 men, color the td red if not color green.

Comment: Using a counter would do the same purpose, without adding another loop. I don't know the performance difference on that, other than removing confusion.